# A central ofﬁce in a company has eight computers operating independently.

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability that any one of them fails in a day is 0.20. Computers are repaired in the evening of each day and made ready for operation the next day.

a) probability that all eight will fail:
(1*.2)+(2*.2)+(3*.2)+(4*.2)+(5*.2)+(6*.2)+(7*.2)+(8*.2) = 7.2
Did i do this correctly? Is the answer right for part a?

b) probability that there will always be a computer available in any day:
Since there's .2 of failing, is availability .8? Is that correct?

Sorry, I'm just really lost. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If we assume independence (so for example no power surges), the probability all eight will fail on a particular day is $(0.2)^8$.  Now b) should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is 7.2. It is more than 1. Bad sign. Probability can not be higher than 1. So, your answer is wrong.

Probability that all 8 computers fail is the probability that all of the following 8 independent events will happen:

1. computer 1 fails
2. computer 2 fails

...

8. computer 8 fails

To find out the probability that several independent events happen you need to multiply probabilities of all these independent events. And the answer would be 0.2*0.2*...*0.2 = 0.2 ** 8 = 0.00000256

You can reason this was. Computer 1 fails only 1 of every 5 days. It's the same as "5 of every 25 days". But there is a computer 2. 4 of these 5 days when computer 1 failed computer 2 works as normal, and only 1 day it fails also. So, both computers fail 1 of 25 days. And so on.

b) probability that there is at least 1 working computer = probability that NOT all the computers fail. So, it is 1 - 0.00000256.

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense.